# ¿How to fix "Insufficient memory to execute this command" issue in SPSS?

Tags: spss

This occurs only when I'm trying to carry out an ANCOVA. Please help me!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the workspace memory.  It is recommended to only do this as needed and to gradually increase it until you're able to run your task.  The below syntax will increase the workspace memory to double the default value (6,184 KB).

```
SET WORKSPACE = 12296 .
```

And you can always check your workspace allocation like this:

```
SHOW WORKSPACE.
```

More detail can be found on the IBM support pages: [IBM support: SPSS memory](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-much-memory-can-spss-windows-use-what-are-mxmemory-and-workspace-and-which-procedures-are-affected)